# SoapClient replaces tags (inside some tag) to htmlentities

Tags: php, xml, laravel, soap-client, html-entities

**The issue:** I am sending SOAP request to 3rd-party server and inside one of my tags I have all "<" ">" replaced with html-entities `&lt;` `&gt;`

**The info:** 
Lets say I have this class(simplified and pseudocoded for clarity):

```
Class SoapSender {
    private $session = 'sessionHash';
    private $soap = new SoapClient(/* settings */);

    public function create() {
        try {
            $agr = [];
            $agr['SessionToken'] = $this->session;
            $agr['Document'] = $this->prepareDocument();

            $request = $this->soap->createRequest($agr); // 3rd-party call

        } catch (SoapFault $f) {
            /* handle exception */
        }
    }
```

The documentation of 3rd-party says that `<Document>` should be XML string so I do this:

```
private function prepareDocument() {
        $arr = [
            /* Create all sub-tags of <Document> */
        ];

        $xml = Formatter::make($arr, 'array')->toXml();
        // this operations required for valid structure
        $xml = str_replace(array('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>','<xml>','</xml>'), '', $xml);
        $xml = str_replace(['Subject_1', 'Subject_2'], 'Subject', $xml);
        $xml = str_replace(['Period_1', 'Period_2'], 'Period', $xml);
        $xml = preg_replace('/Store_[1-9]/', 'Store', $xml);
        return $xml;
```

`Formatter` is [SoapBox/laravel-formatter](https://github.com/SoapBox/laravel-formatter).

Soo, 
when I send request and recieve response with errors I dump `$this->soap->__getLastRequest()` and see that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://someurl.com">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:CreateRequest>
<Document>
&lt;General&gt;&lt;Product&gt;Bread&lt;/Product&gt;&lt;DateBeg&gt;2016-04-04T00:00:00&lt;/DateBeg&gt;&lt;DateEnd&gt;2017-04-03&lt;/DateEnd&gt;&lt;.....
...........blah-blah....
</Document>
<SessionToken>SessionTokeon</SessionToken></ns1:CreateRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**What I have so far:** debuging `prepareDocument` says that I have valid xml string in utf-8 with all tags intact, so encoding them to html-entities happens on SOAP request. Only the `Document` tag gets encoded, others are ok. 
All my other services that use same aproach but different 3rd-party works perfect. Sending this request (but decoded back to normal) by SOAP UI works as it should. All happens inside laravel project.

**The issue again:** I am sending request to 3rd-party server and inside one of my tags I have all "<" ">" replaced with html-entities `&lt;` `&gt;`

**The question:** What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: That's the right way, if it wouldn't, there's no way to differentiate which is the actual data to send because `<` and `>` are used for SOAP to specify the message structure. If you would have the `<` and `>` symbols, you surely would be violating the interface contract in the WSDL.

Comment: @whoan I am deeply sorry, but I totally didn't get you. Are you saying that entities is what should be inside any multi-level tag of request ? if yes then why other 3rd-party API`s work fine without generating entities inside this type of tags? If no, please explain more about __what should I do__

Comment: I say, what about if you need to send some part of a wsdl?, if it doesn't convert the tags, in some cases the soap parser would confuse which is the actual content to send or which is part of the soap structure body.

Comment: @whoan If I understood you right, you mean data inside tags that may break body structure should be escaped, if so then that is not my case, I have only wodrs, dates and numbers inside tags. And valid body structure.